# How to install python packages on Ubuntu bionic?

Tags: python, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

It looks like deadsnakes ppa deprecated the following packages from Ubuntu bionic,
`python3.9 python3.9-dev python3.9-venv python3.9-distutils python3.9-tk`.
Although i installed python 3.9.16 successfully using source code

```
RUN cd /opt \
&& sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.9.16/Python-3.9.16.tgz \
&& tar xzf Python-3.9.16.tgz \
&& cd Python-3.9.16 \
&& sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations \
&& sudo make altinstall \
&& sudo rm -f /opt/Python-3.9.16.tgz
```

I would like to know how can I install the remaining packges (python3.9-dev, python3.9-venv, python3.9-distutils, python3.9-tk). I am not sure if they are installed already as part of Python 3.9.16.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how this is programming related, other that Python is a programming language. Better ask on https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: You'd use `python3.9 -m pip install ...`

Comment: @One `distutils`, `venv`, and `tkinter` are in the stdlib. Ubuntu just packages them separately for space saving. As for `python3.9-dev`, I'm not sure, but I think the same files are in the Python source code.

Comment: 18.04 is out of standard support, so deadsnakes has dropped it. You should upgrade. [ubuntu.se] won't take the question because of that. (FYI @Thomas)

Comment: Related: [How to install Python 3.11 on Ubuntu 18.04.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76648686/4518341)